# My Linksys WRT150N periodically resets itself to factory defaults

Tags: wireless-router, factory-defaults

I have a Linksys WRT150N (wireless N router). Every couple of weeks or so it magically resets itself to factory defaults (no one is messing with it, the power didn't go out, and I have it on a UPS). I am already on the current firmware (v1.01.9), so there's nothing to upgrade to.

Any ideas? Or am I in the market for a new router?

Comment: I would contact Linksys myself.

Comment: @Chris - I posted this on the linksys forum. The response I got (not from linksys, just a user) was to reset to factory defaults and load the current firmware. Ugh.

Comment: Reset to factory defaults is the solution for every problem! LOL, I would get on the phone and call them see if you cannot get it replaced/repaired.

Answer (score 1):

You can save the configuration file to a file on your computer and restore from that saved file every time this happens.  This would make restoration much quicker, but doesn't solve your underlining problem.

Answer (score 1):

You might consider switching to [DD-WRT](http://www.dd-wrt.com/) as your firmware. I had the same problem with a roommate's WRT150N in undergraduate school and I flashed it with DD-WRT and didn't have a problem after that.

It also provides much more functionality for your router. Type "wrt150n" on [this page](http://www.dd-wrt.com/site/support/router-database) to find the info for your router.

Comment: +1 DD-WRT rules.. but I think RMA'ing it may be a better solution as the hardware seems troubled...

Answer (score 0):

The router may reset itself for various reasons. If this keeps happening, it may be due to a common issue. First, try to understand why the router is resetting itself. There are many possible reasons for this.

The router firmware is corrupted.
Outdated firmware.
The wrong firmware has been installed.
Router firmware has been attacked by malware.
Overheating problem.
The Reset button is stuck or pressed by any object.

To fix the router reset itself problem you have to follow the instructions. If your [router reset itself](https://fixotip.com/why-netgear-router-reset-itself-to-factory-settings-and-how-to-fix-it/), here are some quick steps to fix it:

1. Make sure your router is plugged in and turned on.
2. Navigate to your router's main menu (usually found on the front or top of the device).
3. Under "Settings," find "Reset router."
4. Select "Reset router" and confirm your choice.
5. Your router will now reset and return to its default settings.